# Set navigation bar color

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar in my application and i need to customize color like that

[image]

so i but in app delegate this piece of code to customize navigation appearance :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = getColorFromHex("438CC5")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white



}
```

I pick up the color by color picker and put the hex in my code but not getting the same color

any help how can i set specific color to Navigation bar ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case the 
`UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false` should solve the problem. Color could be a little bit different when `isTranslucent` is set to `true`

Be aware of setting the `appearance` will change the navigation bars in you whole app. Consider changing the color of navigation bar explicit from UIViewController like:

```
class Style {
    class func coloredNavigationBar(navigationBar: UINavigationBar?, color: UIColor) {
        navigationBar?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        navigationBar?.barTintColor = color
        navigationBar?.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class FooController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        Style.coloredNavigationBar(navigationBar: navigationController?.navigationBar, color : .red)
    }
}
```